# Autowiring priority

Tags: java, spring, configuration, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

```
<beans default-autowire="byType" />
```

means that all fields of beans will automatically have dependencies injected if there is no more than 1 bean with the desired type.

I wonder if there is a way to define some sort of priority order (based on naming convention for example) for the auto-wiring in the case where there are more than one bean of the desired type.
Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** I just want to add that i'm not allowed to use annotations such as @Component and @Qualifier in the project i'm currently working on.

Comment: So you have a problem, but you are (for unexplained mysterious reasons) "not allowed" to use the solution... This feels more like a silly game (where arbitrary restrictions would make sense) than a real question to me.

Maybe instead of looking for a funky solution fitting the arbitrary requirements, it's time to fix the requirements :)

If there's a real reason the annotations are not the right solution, please explain.

Comment: @Wouter : you're absolutely right, i should have been more clear about why such limitations exist, well the project i am working on is an enterprise application that is already coded an fully functional, what i'm trying to do is to integrate spring into the application and make the framework handle the instantiation of the objects. With thousands of already existing classes that need to be handled by spring (over 20000 to be precise), it's impossible to go through each class and annotate it manually, that would take like forever, that's why i'm trying to perform the wiring programmatically

Answer (score 2):

No there is not, but you can override this behavior as needed for each bean e.g.specify something like this where required:

```
<beans default-autowire="byType" >
    <bean id="..." autowire="byName">
        ....
    </bean>
</beans>
```

From spring 2.5 upwards when using the `<context:component-scan/>` to autowire beans via [`@Autowired`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) you can also add [`@Qualifier`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html) where needed to specify a bean by name if there are multiple beans of the same type.

As stated [in the spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-autowire) there are a few different ways to specify autowiring:

- **no** - do not autowire, this is the default
- **byType** - property type must match bean type, if more than one bean of that type is exists then an exception is thrown
- **byName** - bean name must match property name
- **constructor** - basically the same as byType but for constructors, spring picks the constructor with the most matches
- **autodetect** - same as byType unless there is no default constructor where it falls back to constructor autowiring

Comment: thank you, but that's not really what i need, in fact, all my beans are detected automatically (i'm using <context:component-scan/> and <context:include-filter/>, so i can't do that.

Comment: @Medhi if you are component scanning then you can use the @Autowired annotation, then add @Qualifier where needed, I wil updatemyanswer with more.

Comment: i don't know if you noticed my edit, but as i said above, i'm not allowed to use any kind of annotations in my code.

Comment: that's strange, context:component-scan is specifically for using annotations.

Comment: @ericam no context:component-scan works not only with annotations, but also with user defined filters <context:include-filter/>